# Count number of lines that will be seen by pilot as intersecting in a 2d plane

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, data-structures

The question goes like this:

There are two parallel buildings on each side of the street. N number of ropes are attached from one floor of one building to some another floor of the other building (`(a[i],b[i])` , where `a[i]` is the floor in first building on which `ith` rope is attached to and `b[i]` is the floor on other building) . Now a helicopter is approaching the building. How many intersections of ropes will he be able to see?

You can imagine the tunnel scene from the movie `dark knight` when a GCPD helicopter comes for the rescuing `Harvey dent` but gets strangled by the ropes.

You can imagine the intersections in 2-D plane.
**In the picture attached below pilot will see only one intersection.**

[image]

**APPROACHES**

> 1. The one approach I could think of was brute-force, where I compare each rope with all the other ropes for the intersection. But want to do better than that.
> 2. I thought of sorting the ropes according to the points of contact on any one of the building but couldn't work out.

**NOTES**

> 1. No, it's not from any of the running competitions.
> 2. I just want an approach, not the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sort the pairs according to value a; then iterate over them, and check whether each corresponding value b is greater (or equal if that's ok) than the previous one.

Comment: can you elaborate on this one. any example. i tried your approach with an example, but i think your approach is not correct(or i didnt get completely understood what you meant)?

Comment: Your drawing looks something like [8,8] [6,2] [10,9] [3,4]. Sort by value a: [3,4] [6,2] [8,8] [10,9]. Then iterate over the sorted list and look at b: 4, 2, 8, 9. You'll see that 4 and 2 are in the wrong order, because [3,4] and [6,2] intersect.

Comment: Can you share the link for the problem, so that i can verify if my approach is correct, and later I can share it here.

Answer (score 2):

Put left end positions into binary search tree (RB, AVL), right end positions into sorted array/list, set links to corresponding tree nodes (right end of segment A knows node for left end of A).

```
Walk through array
For every right end:
    get rank R of the left end node
    add (R-1) to result
    remove left end node from the tree
```

Explanation: segment does intersect all other segments, whose left end is upper, and right end is lower

Answer (score 1):

I think you end up by calculating the order of the left ends of the ropes and the order of the right ends of the ropes and each intersection amounts to two ropes which have one above the other on the left side and the other one top on the right side. This is the same calculation is as used for computing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient, and there is a detailed description of calculating this in time O(n log n) at the bottom of that article.

I think you could also compute this by using a data structure which could accept inserts into sorted order and return the position into which the new item was inserted. You could produce such a data structure by taking any of the balanced tree structures and adding a record at each node of the number of descendants below that node.